# Why can I use Google web fonts in CSS without an Internet connection or them being installed locally on my computer?

Tags: google, html, css, fonts

I used a Google font for my website, which isn't stored locally on my computer. When I refresh the page, nothing goes wrong and the font is working fine. However, when I disconnect my Internet connection and I refresh the page, I still see the text in that font. How can that be possible?

Comment: Browser cache ?

Answer (score 2):

Like other page content, the font is cached in your browser so it doesn't have to load the resources each time the page is requested. If you were to clear your browser cache while offline, you would see the font won't load afterwards until you got back online again.